# How to solve locked for checkout in TFS if don't have access to client machine doing the locking

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015

In Visual Studio 2015 Source Control Explorer I select the options `Add Items to Folder`and then `finish`

However I then get an error

> Multiple errors occured during the operation, the first of which is displayed below. A full error list is available in the Output WindowsThe >
>
> item$Folder/ProjectFolder is locked for check-out  Myusername in workspace `MypreviouslaptopName`

`MypreviouslaptopName` was formatted. How am I able to unlock it. I'm using the same username but different computer.

When right click on the folder in Source Control Explorer, the unlock feature is disabled. Lock is enabled. 
If I click locked  but it won't as it says it is already locked by my user on the previous machine.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have Admin access to TFS so was unable to unlock it.

Get Admin access or ask someone who has

Answer (score 0):

team foundation sidekicks has a sidekick that will let you break a lock.

Alternatively, in your case, you could have deleted your old workspace from another laptop by using the "show remote workspace" checkbox on the manage workspaces window.